# What does ['new'] mean in EL expression ${pet['new']}

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, el

In a simple Spring MVC application and I encountered a [strange design](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/pets/createOrUpdatePetForm.jsp#L22): `pet ['new']`. I haven't seen this construction before and need someone to explain the semantics of it. It likely refers to [this class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/PetController.java#L68).

Second line

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${pet['new']}">
        <c:set var="method" value="post"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="method" value="put"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initCreationForm(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Owner owner = this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownerId);
    Pet pet = new Pet();
    owner.addPet(pet);
    model.put("pet", pet);
    return "pets/createOrUpdatePetForm";
}
```

Comment: Could you include the examples in the question to save people from hunting around please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JavaBean property 'foo' of a bean 'bar' can be accessed with two forms of syntax: `bar.foo` or `bar['foo']`. They chose the second one here, to refer to the `new` bean property, i.e. to the `isNew()` getter in BaseEntity.

So the test is equivalent to the Java code

```
if (pet.isNew())
```

Comment: Wow, I even noticed `isNew()` method. Thanks a lot for explanation.

Comment: Answer would be better if it explained why the author used `${pet['new']}` instead of `${pet.new}`.

Comment: @BalusC I agree, but I don't have the definitive answer. I haven't found `new` in the list of reserved words in the specs. So either I missed it, or some server implementation has a problem with `pet.new` and `pet['new']` was used to circumvent it, or the author thought it would cause a problem, and anticipated it. Feel free to edit my answer if you have the explanation.